# Select Count with prepared statement isn't working

Tags: php, mysql

I am making php prepared statement to count number of rows where IMEI equals to a value received from my app. the select count isn't working in the below statement and I can't figure why?

I removed "Count" from the select query and I can retrieve the value successfully, so the problem only with the Count function. any help please.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("x", "y", "z", "w");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$Result2;

$IMEI= $_POST["IMEI"]; 

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT IMEI FROM Users WHERE (IMEI=?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("s", $IMEI);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Result);
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
$Result2  = $Result;
}
$stmt->close();
}
else{
$mysqli->close();    
}

echo ($Result2);

?>
```

Comment: Try SELECT COUNT(IMEI) FROM Users WHERE (IMEI=?). Also look into using PDO, it makes things much easier.

Comment: thanks, I tried that but the problem still there, no thing echoed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your query wants to look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(IMEI) FROM Users WHERE (IMEI=?)
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, I just want to count, I changed to SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM Users WHERE (IMEI=?) .. but the problem still exist

Comment: no error, just nothing as a result of (echo). and I am sure the IMEI value exists as I can retrieve it if I remove "Count". it should echo (2).

Comment: Hmm, have you tried the query in MySQL Workbench or whatever DB admin tool you're using?

Comment: I will check it and feed u back

Comment: No, It is not Working and showing this error:  "SELECT COUNT IMEI FROM Users WHERE (IMEI=b647eee83194af37) LIMIT 0, 25"

Comment: That's not the error message, thats the query. Does it say anything else with this? What data type is IMEI?

Comment: Yes, this is the error sorry, "#1054 - Unknown column 'b647eee83194af37' in 'where clause'
"

Comment: If you change the query to this: SELECT COUNT IMEI FROM Users WHERE (IMEI='b647eee83194af37') LIMIT 0, 25 in your db environment does it work?

Comment: error: #1054 - Unknown column 'COUNT' in 'field list'

Comment: Try this: SELECT COUNT(IMEI) FROM Users WHERE (IMEI='b647eee83194af37') LIMIT 0, 25 - The count needs to know what its counting, sorry. So you want IMEI in the brackets

Comment: oooh, this finally works!! .. let me understand .. why should I use limit 0,25? and how to apply this in the prepared statement?

Comment: @SheriffSaidElahl You don't need the Limit at all, that just Limits the amounts of results. The issue is to do with the IMEI parameter. I imagine in the DB IMEI is a text field. You were passing in b647eee83194af37 which is not a text field according to MySQL. To compare a text field you need to put the data in quotes. I.e 'b647eee83194af37'

Comment: ooh yes, many thanks, I found another problem .. there must be no space between count and the counted column .. Select Count(IMEI) .. not Select Count (IMEI) .. in the second case it considered "Count" as a column in the db. Many thanks Andrew, you saved my day

Comment: I actually don't do PHP, I assume you have turned IMEI into text in PHP now for it to work?  I know how to do it MySQL using concat if you haven't done it yet. Anyway I don't really understand your other problem? If you want the count to have another name change it to: COUNT(IMEI) AS YourNAME

Comment: no problem now, I was just telling that I had a problem that I was leavinf a space between count and (IMEI) like this "Count (IMEI)", which resulted an error. now everything is working. many thanks

Comment: @SheriffSaidElahl No problem, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Just put the column IMEI inside parentheses:

```
SELECT COUNT(IMEI) FROM Users WHERE IMEI=?
```

Comment: If you quote the placeholder it is not a placeholder, it is a literal question mark.

Comment: Sorry, Thought it's really equals to QuestionMark

Comment: Nope, the `?` is swapped by the driver with the `$_POST` value because of the `$stmt->bind_param("s", $IMEI)`, after the execute. The driver handles the quoting.